# Why do some windows applications execute parallely on 64-bit machine

Tags: windows, 64-bit

Why do **`Notepad`** and **`Calculator`** launch differently on 64-bit machine

> **Why do calculator gets launched independently but not notepad?**

This behaviour is not observed on 32 bit machine.

Below is a **testapps.bat** file to test application execution

```
:: File-  testapps.bat

notepad  
        :: wait for notepad to close

mspaint  
    :: wait for notepad to close

calc     
    :: ---- Parallel launch Why? we are suppose to wait here? (this works in 32 bit)

write    
    :: wait for wordpad to close
```

[image: calculator launched]

[image: Notepad launched]

Comment: Calculator on Windows 10 is a UWP the other programs are all Win32 applications.